# How to read values dynamically from a file for a property in updateAttribute?

Tags: apache, minify, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

I added some custom properties in the 'updateAttribute' processor using the '+' button. For example: I declared a property 'DBConnectionURL' and gave the value as 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test'. Then, in the 'DBCPConnectionPool' service controller, I simple used the value'${DBConnectionURL}' for 'Database Connection URL' property. But, I manually gave the value for 'DBConnectionURL' property.I want a way where I can feed the value dynamically from a file, so that i just need to change the value in the file and the value for 'DBConnectionURL' changes dynamically based on the value present in the file. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rishab,

You have to use nifi variable registry.

In conf/nifi.properties, you could configure the below configuration in it for dynamically update a value in your data flow.

```
nifi.variable.registry.properties=./dynamic.properties
```

You can give your variables in that file dynamic.properties it should present in conf directory.

For an example, If dynamic.properties files contains below values

```
DBCPURL= jdbc://<host>:<port>
```

you can use that in your data flow by using `${DBCPURL}`

**Note:** You should restart nifi services if you change any configuration in conf/nifi.properties.Otherwise your changes not worked in dataflow.

Feel free to accept it be answer if it worked for you.

Comment: As of (I believe) NiFi 1.5.0, you can also set variables directly on the Process Group (including the root PG) from the UI, by right-clicking and selecting "Variables". That is kind of an inline "variable registry" such that you don't need the file based one described above.

Comment: @Mahendra Prabhu

It worked. Thanks a Lot. You are awsome :)

Comment: Dont hesitate to accept it as answer because it may be helpful for someone

Comment: @Mahendraprabhu We deal with multiple databases, so if the source DB changes from MySQl to Oracle, I have to manually change the values in 'dynamic.properties' file. I need to automate this. One way is that we can have multiple properties file for each database like: MySQL.properties, Oracle. Properties. But how can we dynamically generate 'DBCPConnectionPool' service for every properties file? I mean, if source DB changes 'DBCPConnectionPool' service must automatically read the values only from that properties file which is defined for that particular database but not from any other file.

Comment: You can create three dbcpconnectionpool in which pts out the various properties values and then use with respect to your case.

Comment: @Mahendraprabhu If I create three DBCPConnectionPool I manually need to change the DBCPConnectionPool every time there is a change in the source database. In such case I can directly give the respective values for each DBCPConnectionPool. So there is no point in creating three different files if i manually have to do that. I want it to happen automatically

Comment: There is no other way beacause jdbcConnectionpool doesn't have the expression language support.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168380/discussion-between-rishab-prasad-and-mahendra-prabhu).